# Ubuntu 18.04.3: after entering login password - Desktop is blank; Even after reinstall

Tags: boot, 18.04, gnome, xorg, gdm

I have checked this: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

- But all of this is about issue just after booting and before logging to Ubuntu. For me, I am able to boot successfully, and issue is only after entering password on Ubuntu Login Page.

My Nvidia graphic card has been working for quite some time now and my laptop was fine, it happened suddenly.

I have Google chrome and certain other software setup in cron, and they open normally, without any issue, after booting up.

Just that, the Gnome desktop is blank (**nothing except wallpaper**) , and when I drag my mouse on the Gnome desktop it becomes a cross symbol instead of normal mouse symbol. I can't do Alt + Tab, to switch between the windows. Not able to minimize or maximize any window. Can't type Windows+, shortcut to switch to Gnome desktop.

I saw `dmesg`, but there is no error related to this issue. Facing same issue after reboot (with normal complete shutdown). I am not using wayland on my Ubuntu 18.04.3. And I am using Gnome desktop.

Any suggestions?

---

## Tried:

- Booting into an older kernel.
- Repaired dpkg packages in recovery mode (nothing to repair)
- Booting with usb (with 18.04.3), and did fsck repair.
- Did sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
- I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04.3 but I am facing same issue! I have separate home partition.

Answer (score 1):

I manually executed `gnome-shell` from terminal and the issue was resolved!

Comment: Was this persistent or do you have to type `gnome-shell` each boot?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: It was for sure due to some configuration file related to `gnome-shell` in my Home directory. I use Backintime to backup my Home directory. And by mistake I had renamed every file in my home directory with a backup restore process from backintime. The restore failed due to some reasons, but all my files in home directory got renamed with the suffix backup. This would have caused for the configuration files to be autogenerated, and issue got resolved. Are you aware of these configuration files for gnome-shell in Home directory?